# Terminal not working in WebStorm 11.0.4 in Mac

Tags: node.js, terminal, webstorm

I have already installed Node.js and I am  able to run my existing project in Visual Studio or Sublime Text and terminal in Visual Studio is working perfectly fine.

But when I am trying to run the same project in WebStorm then terminal is not recognizing `node`, `npm` n all.

May be some setting is missing in WebStorm. Need help to resolve the same.

Comment: Try launching WebStorm from terminal in first place -- any difference?

Answer (score 1):

In WebStorm | Preferences for macOS, and click Node.js and NPM under Languages & Frameworks

The term local Node.js interpreter denotes a Node.js installation on your computer. You must write your local path for Node.js